# expect and DES encryption

Tags: linux, encryption, passwords, expect, des

I want to write a expect script to login to our routers/switches (Cisco). It is working but the problem is that the password is in cleartext form in my script. That is why I want to make it encrypted like:
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Secure+expect
Problem now is that I imported tcllib, can make

```
package require des
```

but when I want to use the command des, like in the example script, I get:

```
expect1.1> package require des
1.1.0
expect1.2> des
invalid command name "des"
    while executing
"des"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at the manual: https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/des/des.html

Comment: There are a couple of angles here. If you intend to run this **as a scheduled job**, then you have to store the encryption key in order to use it, and an attacker would also have access to that key, so the encryption will be useless. If you intend to only run this **interactively**, you can either A) prompt the user for the password (so no storage is required), or B) use a password vault tied to users' own authentication to check out the needed password.

Comment: Second one. I am working for an ISP and have to login to multiple Routers/Switches everyday.